# Question On Route Aggregation

Tags: routing, router, ip-address

Suppose I have these 3 IP Prefixes :

> **190.154.27.0/26** **190.154.27.64/26** **190.154.27.192/26**

and I want find the aggregate prefix.

I convert each address to its' binary equivalent:

```
10111110.10011010.00011011.00000000
10111110.10011010.00011011.01000000
10111110.10011010.00011011.11000000
```

And we see that the common pattern lasts until the end of the third octet (24 digits). So shouldn't the aggregate be 190.154.27.0/24 ? Why is it 190.154.26.0/23 ?

Comment: That is explained in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the prefixes *without their length* is not sufficient. You need to make sure that you don't inadvertently aggregate subnets in between.

One method would be to decrease a prefix length by one bit and check if the resulting prefix encompasses more/all other subnets.

In your example,

```
A. 190.154.27.0/26 (190.154.27.0 - 190.154.27.63)
B. 190.154.27.64/26 (190.154.27.64 - 190.154.27.127)
C. 190.154.27.192/26 (190.154.27.192 - 192.154.27.255)
```

A and B can be cleanly aggregated to 190.154.27.0/25. Note that 190.154.27.0/24 also includes an additional subnet, 190.154.27.128/26 which may or may not be a problem.

190.154.26.0/23 also includes the entire 190.154.26.0/24 subnet. You're not giving a clue to why that should be required.

Comment: I'm reading the book TCP/IP Illustrated and it has a very incomprehensible example. So if the addition of the 190.154.27.128/26 subnet isn't a problem then for those 3 subnets the correct aggregate is 190.154.27.0/24 right ?

Comment: Yes. I've broken down the subnets into start/end addresses above. I hope it makes it easier to comprehend.

Comment: I've just pulled the book and that's pretty much what it says in there, too.

Comment: I just couldn't understand why the 190.154.26.0/24 should be added. You made me get that this subnet is an extra. Thank you very much.